# Cassandra Accessor and "CQL" injection

Tags: java, security, cassandra, code-injection, cql

Is a select query made by a java driver accessor vulnerable to injection?

Some like

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id")
Result<Entity> byId(@Param("id") String id);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, This syntax does not perform string replacement. It actually binds the value into a parameter slot. This means a malicious request would simply be treated as the id within a bound statement.